# Unable to import functions from modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I tried to create a module using `setup.py` to practise my understanding of packages and `__init__.py` files. But I get the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thoma/PycharmProjects/test_gymnasium/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from test_final_1 import my_add
ImportError: cannot import name 'my_add' from 'test_final_1' (/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/test_gymnasium/lib/python3.8/site-packages/test_final_1/__init__.py)
```

Here's the structure of my Python folder `test-final-1` -

```
├── build
│   ├── bdist.linux-x86_64
│   └── lib
│       └── test_final_1
│           ├── calc.py
│           └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
├── test_final_1
│   ├── calc.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── test_final_1.egg-info
    ├── dependency_links.txt
    ├── PKG-INFO
    ├── requires.txt
    ├── SOURCES.txt
    └── top_level.txt
```

The `__init__` file contains the following -

```
from test_final_1.calc import *
```

The `calc` file contains the following  -

```
def my_add(a,b):
    return a+b

def my_sub(a,b):
    return a-b
```

Here is my `test` file which throws an error -

```
from test_final_1 import my_add
a = 2
b = 4
my_add(2,4)
```

Here is the `setup` file -

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="test_final_1",
    version="0.0.1",
    install_requires=[],
)
```

This is how I run the `setup` file from the parent directory - `pip install e .`

**Edit 1**

Based on of the comments I received, I went to `site-packages`. Here I observed that, the `__init__` file is the same. But the `calc` file is strangely empty. Why would that have happened?

Comment: What does `/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/test_gymnasium/lib/python3.8/site-packages/test_final_1/calc.py` contain? The file you're looking at may not match the installed version. (If this file contains something unexpected, **do not manually edit it**. Uninstall the package, rebuild, and reinstall.)

Comment: (Also check `/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/test_gymnasium/lib/python3.8/site-packages/test_final_1/__init__.py`.)

Comment: @user2357112 The `__init__` file is the same. But the `calc` file is strangely empty. Why would that have happened?

Comment: Maybe you installed it before you actually wrote the contents for that file.

Comment: No, I checked. I even reinstalled it multiple times.